# CentOS, cannot create ftp user

Tags: linux, ftp, centos, cpanel, whm

I have VPS and I installed cPanel & WHM and everything works, but i tried to add user with "`useradd -m user -d /home/cs/user`" and it worked, I added password and tried to login in ftp, and it can't..I tried to change password, but again, nothing.

I installed vsftpd and when i start it, it says failed.

How can i fix it ? And how can I add users so ftp for them can work ?

Sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 0):

cPanel by default has pure-ftpd ftp server. VSFTPD is failing because pure-ftpd is running.

You have two options.

1. Stop pure-ftpd and then start vsftpd.

OR

2. You will have to create accounts from WHM to make ftp work.

Login to WHM >> create new account >>  put some dummy domain name in domain field.